# Как заменить слово в строке, только если около слова нет символов?

Tags: java

Например, у меня есть строка `привет приветик привет`. Как я могу заменить все *`привет`* на `приветик`, не трогая изначальное слово `приветик`(иначе получится `приветик` **приветикик** `приветик`)?

Comment: А что Вы уже пробовали?  :)

Comment: Ну, я пытался разобраться с помощью регулярных выражений (которые я только вчера начал изучать), неполучилось , не нашел ответа в гугле и задал вопрос здесь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью регулярного выражения:

```
String s = "привет приветик привет";
s = s.replaceAll("привет(?!\\S)","приветик");
```

А если надо, чтобы слово было с обеих сторон окружено пробелами, то регулярное выражение нужно написать так: `(?<!\\S)привет(?!\\S)`.

Скобочки со знаком вопроса и равно называются `Lookaround`. Можете почитать об этом в интернете.

---

P.S.: переделал: раньше было (?= |$), которое лучше заменить на (?=\\s|$).

Comment: Спасибо, но не могли бы вы мне немного объяснить что здесь к чему(моя некомпетентность)

Comment: Изучите регулярные выражения.

Comment: Спасибо , буду.

Answer (score 0):

Очень грубо и топорно, но результат вроде тот, что Вы хотели...

```
        public class TestClass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new TestClass().run();
        }

        public void run() {
            Scanner keyboardScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String inString = keyboardScanner.nextLine();
            String shortMessage = shortifyMessage(inString);
            System.out.println(shortMessage);
        }

        public String shortifyMessage(String str) {
            String s = str;
            s = s.replace("привет" , "приветик");        
            s = s.replace("приветикик", "приветик");
             return s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Извините, но это не совсем то, что я хотел.. Я написал обстрагированно, т.е. вместо слова `привет` и `приветик` пользователь мог бы написать любые другие